# Jasmine test fails Expected undefined to equal

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have written an angular test to test httpstatus 0 code returned when the service is not available.
While running the test I am getting the following error. What is the possible issue here

```
Testing the interceptor class > making http calls > Adds a deliberate error code 0
Error: Expected undefined to equal 0.

Expected undefined to equal 'deliberate 0 error -  Unknown Error'.
Error: Expected undefined to equal 'deliberate 0 error -  Unknown Error'.
```

**Update : I have updated the unit test code which includes the definition for interceptor class which might help with diagnosing the issue**

Unit  Test

```
 import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpWebInterceptor } from './httpWebInterceptor.service';

import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { OfflineComponent } from '../components/offline/offline.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AlertService } from './alert.service';

class MockUser {
    clientCompanyId: number;
}

class MockAuthService  {
    get currentUser() : MockUser {
        let user = {clientCompanyId : 4};
        return user;
    }
}

class MockAlertService {
    resetStickyMessage() {

    }
}

describe('Testing the interceptor class', function () {

    let httpWebInterceptor: HttpWebInterceptor;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
    let httpClient: HttpClient;   


    let routerSpy = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') };

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                OfflineComponent
            ],
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
                   { path: 'offline', component: OfflineComponent }
               ])
            ],
            providers: [HttpWebInterceptor,
                { provide: AlertService, useClass: MockAlertService },
                { provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService },
                { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpWebInterceptor, multi: true },               
                { provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy }
            ],

        });




        httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
        httpWebInterceptor = TestBed.get(HttpWebInterceptor);

    });



    describe('making http calls', () => {
        it('Adds a deliberate error code 0', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {            

            spyOn(console, 'error');

            const fakeUrl = "http://localhost:57973/"; 
            const mockErrorResponse = { status: 0, statusText: 'deliberate 0 error -  Unknown Error' };
            const emsg = 'deliberate 0 error -  Unknown Error';
            let errResponse: any;

            http.get(fakeUrl).subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    fail('deliberate 0 error -  Unknown Error');
                },
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {                    
                    expect(error.status).toEqual(0, 'status');
                    expect(error.error).toEqual(emsg, 'message');
                });

            const req = httpMock.expectOne(fakeUrl);
            httpMock.verify();
            req.flush(emsg, { status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error' });
            expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['offline']);
            expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();

        }));

    });



    describe('making http calls', () => {
        it('Adds a deliberate error code 404', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {

            spyOn(console, 'error');

            const fakeUrl = "http://localhost:57973/";

            const emsg = 'deliberate 404 error - Not Found';

            http.get(fakeUrl).subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    fail('should have failed with the 404 error');
                },
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    expect(error.status).toEqual(404, 'status');
                    expect(error.error).toEqual(emsg, 'message');
                });


            const req = httpMock.expectOne(fakeUrl);
            req.flush(emsg, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found' });

            // toHaveBeenCalledWith() looks at all the spy's calls. Use instead toEqual()
            expect(routerSpy.navigate).not.toEqual(['offline']);

            expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));

    });



});
```

**Update 2: Interceptor class**

```
import { Injectable, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpStatusCode } from '../services/system-constants';
import { AlertService, MessageSeverity } from '../services/alert.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpWebInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(public router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private alertService: AlertService
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log('event', event);
                    if(event.status == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                         if (this.router.url == '/offline') {
                             // Website is back online
                             console.log('redirecting to login');
                             this.authService.gotoLoginPage();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.error instanceof Error) {
                    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
                    if(isDevMode()) console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if(isDevMode()) 
                        console.error('Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: ${error.error}');

                    switch(error.status)
                    {
                        case HttpStatusCode.Unknown:
                        {
                            if (this.router.url != '/offline')
                            {

                                this.authService.clearUserData();
                                this.alertService.resetStickyMessage();
                                this.alertService.showMessage("No Network", "The server cannot be reached", MessageSeverity.error);
                                this.router.navigate(['offline']);
                                break;
                            } 
                        }
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                    return throwError(error);

            }));

    }
}
```

**Update 3: Mock classes**

```
class MockAuthService  {
    get currentUser() : MockUser {
        let user = {clientCompanyId : 4};
        return user;
    }

    clearUserData() {

    }
}

class MockAlertService {
    resetStickyMessage() {

    }

    showMessage() {

    }
}
```

Comment: flush() is used to actually send a HTTP response from the fake backend. To simulate the absence of a backend or a network error, use error(): https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/TestRequest#error

Comment: Please add the unit of code you are trying to test to the question.

Comment: Sorry unit of code ? You mean the entire file ?

Comment: The error.status here is coming undefined . Isn’t this specific issue of the test code itself as I am mocking

Comment: @Tom You test accepts `http: HttpClient` but in the test body you use `httpClient`, is just a typo, or it's a different client? There is a message about an interceptor, do you use any? I guess the interceptor may be a reason, because the test from the sample above passes, I've tried it.

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov , i have updated to code with the interceptor class

Comment: @Tom But the interceptor sources is still missing. Did you try to run tests without the interceptor?

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov , I have updated the post with  the interceptor class

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov. Sorry I thought your mentioned the actual code that i have written the test for. The describe is written within the interceptor class. How would it run without setting the providers etc

Comment: Also I have written the test to test the HttpWebInterceptor class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that the `MockAuthService` & `MockAlertService` don't not completely implement the classes they mock. For example `MockAuthService.clearUserData()` is missing in the mock implementation. Because of this, there should be a runtime error in the browser console, and you get the test failed. I've reproduced the problem with the same errors that you have.

Probably it's better to implement the mocks from the original classes to get compile errors, if some functionality is missing, like:

```
class MockAuthService implements AuthService { ... }
```

Another approach is to use jasmine mocks. In this case the compiler won't warn you if some method is missing, but the mocking becomes easier, like:

```js
const authServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<AuthService>(AuthService.name, [
    'gotoLoginPage',
    'clearUserData'
]);
```

You can provide it like:

```js
{ provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceMock }
```

Every method in the mock is a spy now, so you can check it like other spies, like:

```js
expect(authServiceMock.gotoLoginPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: I thinjk you are right. I ahve updated the post with mock classes. could you confirm if its ok to write blank methods

Comment: @Tom Of course, if the methods don't affect the behavior you test, It's ok to leave these methods empty.